# Sorting in hugo

Tags: hugo

In the following piece of code

```
{{ range $.Site.Data.clients.Clients }}
    <div class="col-md-6 client">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <img class="logo" src="{{ .Logo }}"></img>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <p class="description">{{ .Description }}</p>
            <p class="caption">{{ .Caption }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{{ end }}
```

I want to preserve the order as they occur in my /data/clients.yaml file. How?

As for now I added a count field in order to do this :

```
{{ range sort $.Site.Data.clients.Clients "Count" }}
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use yaml lists.

```
Fruits:
    - Apple
    - Orange
    - Strawberry
    - Mango
```